# Failed to open both Excel document and SWT application with Win32OLE embedded objects same time

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I am having issue with Win32OLE opening Excel documents with embedded objects over Windows 64 bits. I can open both SWT application with OLE embedded object and Excel documents separately for review my each updates in the sheet.

However, I am not able to open both Excell documents and SWT application with OLE object in Windows 64 bits.

I am using the following environment:

1. JDK: jdk1.8.0_91 64-Bit
2. OS: Windows 7 Professional 64-Bit
3. Service Pack 1
4. JAR: jre1.8.0_91 64-Bit
5. Microsoft Office: 2016 64-Bit

### Here is my code:

```
OleClientSite clientSite ;
try {
    clientSite = new OleClientSite(frame, SWT.NONE, new File(filelocation));
} catch (SWTException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    disposeClient();
}

if (clientSite != null){
    clientSite.doVerb(OLE.OLEIVERB_SHOW); // Show property use
    hideToolbars(clientSite);
}

//Hide Toolbar and menubar
public static void hideToolbars(OleClientSite site) {
    int result = site.queryStatus(OLE.OLECMDID_HIDETOOLBARS);
    if ((result & OLE.OLECMDF_SUPPORTED) == OLE.OLECMDF_SUPPORTED) {
        site.exec(OLE.OLECMDID_HIDETOOLBARS, OLE.OLECMDEXECOPT_DODEFAULT, new Variant(), new Variant());
    }
}

// Dispose object
void disposeClient() {
    if (clientSite != null)
        clientSite.dispose();
    clientSite = null;
}
```

Thanks
Lalit